# Meaning of "Object allocation: LINQ method call"

Tags: c#, rider

I use JetBrains Rider for programming in C#. Often, Rider underscores some operations in my code like the following one `list.Where` LINQ method call:

[image]

When I put my mouse cursor over the`Where` keyword, it shows the following message:

[image]

The compilation doesn't generate any warnings nor the Rider itself shows any warnings. But then what is the meaning of it ?

Comment: You have a plugin installed, probably "Heap Allocations Viewer", which highlights code that allocates objects. It is not a warning, nor an error, and nothing the compiler cares about. You might want to use this kind of plugin if you're writing games, as an example, where you want to avoid garbage collections at all costs.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thank you very much! I have just deactivated the "Heap Allocations Viewer" and this highlighting is gone. I always wondered what it was! Can you put this as an answer and I will upvote and close it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The highlight comes from a plugin, "Heap Allocations Viewer".

The highlight is there to inform you of code that does allocations, boxing, unboxing, etc.

These things *may* mean something to you, but usually only if you're dealing with a very constrained execution environment or constrained execution profiles, such as low-memory embedded systems or games programming, where memory allocations or garbage collections are something you want to avoid if you can.

If you don't really care about what this plugin is telling you, you can safely disable or remove it from Rider by going to File->Settings->Plugins and searching for it.

The reason that the compiler neither warns nor produces an error about this is that the code is in fact completely benign and unproblematic, but it has some sideeffects that you may want to avoid in lieu of the situations described above.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are materializing the collection (i.e. .ToList()) it is just informing you that memory will be allocated to store the new collection when you don't *need* do (i.e. leave it as an IEnumerable by removing the ToList())

Comment: It says that `.Where` is allocating an object, which is true. Why it's not highlighting `ToList` *as well* I don't know.

Comment: Actually, if I remove `.ToList()`, it doesn't change anything. It is still highlight the `Where` method.

Comment: no, this is not about materializing collection with ToList. this is about creation iterator object inside of Where(...). iterator is reference-type, so instance will be allocated on heap. this is exactly what this highlighting is about.

Comment: ToList() isn't highlighted because it's pretty explicit, that memory will be allocated. just like creating new list with new-keyword. but this plugin highlights IMplicit allocations